# Sentencia INSERT MySQL PHP, insertar solo x registros en una tabla de varios campos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, registro

tengo una duda al momento de realizar un `INSERT INTO` desde PHP.
Tengo una tabla que es la siguiente:  [image: Tabla registro]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para solo insertar dos registros en esta table con muchos campos? Yo quiero insertar únicamente el correo y el registro desde un primer formulario y luego desde otro formulario terminar de rellenar la tabla con los datos que faltan por ingresar.

[image: Intrucción SQL]

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo "altas.php", esa es la instrucción, pero no sé cómo hacer para que solo ingrese dos registros en la tabla. He probado poniendo todos los nombres de las columnas, también en VALUES poniendo solo comillas simples '', pero no he conseguido que funcione.

Espero alguien pueda echarme una mano.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: en tu codigo estas haciendo el insert solo de correo y clave. Una vez hecho el insert (si es que tu bbdd te lo permite), se habrá generado el id de ese registro. Tienes que recuperarlo para usarlo en el siguiente formulario. En ese formulario, en lugar de un INSERT deberás hacer un UPDATE.

Comment: ahora que he vuelto a leer tu duda, me pregunto: Solo has escrito la consulta de INSERT? no la has ejecutado con una conexion de bbdd y su correspondiente comando query?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Cuando dices "Tienes que recuperarlo para usarlo..." a qué te refieres exactamente¿?
Me dijeron que para ingresar solo dos campos de 10 por ejemplo, los 8 restantes tengo que ponerlos con comillas '', y pienso que sería algo así `INSERT INTO registro (correo, clave) VALUES('$correo', '$clave','','','','', etc. etc)` Pero he sido incapaz de conseguir que funcione. No sé en qué puedo fallar, será problema de la bbdd¿? Será problema del Nulo¿? ya que en la BBDD pone que todos son Nulos. No sé si me explico. 
Sí tengo una conexión a la bbdd y funciona.

Comment: Tu modelo de BBDD indica que todos los campos deben estar definidos (no pueden ser null). Por lo tanto, si solo quieres indicar dos campos, tu consulta tiene que tener los campos faltantes con el valor ''. Eso que te han dicho es correcto. Lo que te pasa es que la primera parte de la consulta TAMBIEN deben estar definidos. Sería algo como "insert into registro (correo, clave, nombre, edad, sexo,objetivo, peso_actual, peso_deseado, actividad, disponibilidad) values ('$correo', '$clave', '','','','','','','')"

Answer (score 1):

El modelo presentado indica que todos los campos son obligatorios. Esto implica que la consulta debe incluir todos los campos.

El problema que se plantea (insertar unicamente 2 campos) no seria correcto inicialmente. Existe una solución (indicar los campos restantes con un valor vacío o espacio en blanco) para "solventar" este problema, pero es muy probable que esto no corresponda a la lógica de negocio (puesto que el modelo de bbdd quiere "obligar" a introducir todos los datos).

al margen de esto ultimo, si queremos aplicar esa "solución", en cualquier caso, hay que indicar TODOS los campos en la primera parte de la consulta, y poner los valores que nos faltan como espacios en blanco.

Si tu formulario para indicar valores solo recoge 'correo' y 'clave', tu código quedaría tal como:

```
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registro (correo, clave, edad, sexo, objetivo, peso_actual, peso_deseado, actividad, disponibilidad) 
                      VALUES ('$correo', '$clave', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '');";
```

dado que no tenemos mas datos (temas de edad mínima, pesos por defecto y demás) y como los campos `edad`, `peso_actual`, `peso_deseado` son enteros, he puesto por defecto el valor 0. Esto deberías decidirlo de alguna manera (no parece correcto una edad 0, pero esto es lo que puede ocurrirte si no se puede pedir el dato).

Comment: Además, habría otros temas a tratar, como que la `edad` es un campo variable dependiendo del día en que se hace la consulta, por lo que siempre conviene pedir una `fechadenacimiento`, y no una edad que variará con el tiempo). Y por supuesto, revisar si la sentencia SQL se ejecuta después del pantallazo que has puesto o no, claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Jakala. Me sirvió bastante y me ha funcionado.